# Hibernate file location in maven web application

Tags: hibernate, maven, web-applications

I am writing a simple web application with maven (web application archetype) and I am not sure where to put Hibernate config files. Which is the correct folder?

Currently, I have them inside my webapp/WEB-INF folder but the application does not seem to find them.

EDIT: thanks for the answers. I am not sure whether the app found the config file or not. It just produces this exception: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/dom4j/DocumentException`

I added the dependency:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Does this mean that the app found the config files and something else is wrong or do I still have the location wrong?

EDIT2:
This is the method used for saving with hibernate:

```
private void saveToDatabase(Customer customer) {
        // 1. configuring hibernate
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();

        // 2. create sessionfactory
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();

        // 3. Get Session object
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

        // 4. Starting Transaction
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();

        session.save(customer);
        transaction.commit();
```

}

hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/carrent</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="format_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create </property>
        <mapping resource="customer.hbm.xml" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

customer.hbn.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="wa2.entities.Customer" table="CUSTOMER">
        <id column="ID" name="id" type="java.lang.String" />n
        <property column="NAME" name="name" type="java.lang.String" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: Try in `webapp/WEB-INF/classes`. Unless you have configured hibernate to load the file from somwhere else...  so adding the code which you use to initialize hibernate might be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create at `src/main/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml` the project structure should be like this [image] 
you can follow this [link](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/quick-start-maven-hibernate-mysql-example/) for further clarification

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I edited my question... I still got some errors so I am not 100% sure if the location of the config files is the problem or something else...

Comment: change artifact-id ti  dom4j-1.6.1.jar

Comment: Ok, tried it but it produces an error (Eclipse says its missing the artifact)

Comment: change it back to 
<dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
then run

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72464/discussion-between-teddy-and-smajl).

Answer (score 0):

In your Maven web project you have a folder called `src/main/resources`.  Put your `hibernate.cfg.xml` file in that folder.